Is it possible to get parent and one more parent id using sitecore token?
Is it possible to get parent and one more parent id name using Sitecore tokens?
Ex:
Sitecore 
---- content 
----- Site1
------ Department page
------- page components
-------- CSE 
example: consider "cse" is the child item. I need to get the item id/name of department page item. Is that any option to get item id using Sitecore tokens?

Are you looking for creating this token to make the query inside the field type..Can you please elaborate the use case in order to suggest the apt solution.
